# Where is the flaw in this reasoning? Change of variables

Tags: calculus

We make the change of variables $x = -w$, $dx = -dw$, and change the limits of integration to obtain

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \log|x| \; dx &=& -\int_0^\infty \frac{w^2}{1+w^4} \log|-w| \; dw \\
&=& -\int_0^\infty \frac{w^2}{1+w^4} \log w \; dw
\end{eqnarray*}$

But this is clearly wrong, since $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \log|x|$ is an even function. Where is the mistake?

Comment: After the substitution you get the integral $\int_{\infty}^0\dots$. Flipping the limits gives you another negative sign.

Comment: I see. Thanks you!

Comment: @MihaHabič Please do post this as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You skipped a step in your manipulation, which led to your confusion. When you introduced the substitution $x=-w$, you changed the bounds of integration, but not appropriately. Your first line should read
$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\log|x|\,dx = 
-\int_{\infty}^0\frac{w^2}{1+w^4}\log|w|\,dw$$
We then flip the bounds to get the usual orientation, which produces another negative sign. Therefore
$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\log|x|\,dx = 
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{w^2}{1+w^4}\log|w|\,dw$$
as expected.